# how to convert video farmat

Tags: video, image-processing, fpga

I am using a IP core (from Xilinx ISE) which has an input video in YCbCr format (3*8 bit). how can I convert RGB format into YCbCr? ( the video generator used for preparing video, generates it in RGB format)

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search returns this result.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff635643.aspx